# Any Particular IDE for web application development?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

Basically my intention is to create web application. I have to use js, ajax, jquery, html5, css etc... I would like to know if there is a web application development kit out there that helps me compile and debug my code? I am aware of "Aptana", but I am not sure if that is what I need. Can someone please eloberate what the choices available to me are. Total noob here to web development so I would like something that helps me learn as I go ahead developing!

Comment: Komodo Edit: http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second Komode IDE (paid) or Komode Edit (free as in open source).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a compiler for js,ajax and jquery, all based on [javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) which is a script language. [Php](http://www.joedolson.com/glossary.php) is a server side language so you need to run your own server on your machine (you may find interesting [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) which provide you php,mysql,apache with a simple setup. About the IDE there are a lot out there, maybe [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) as a free solution is a good idea, or [PHPedit](http://www.phpedit.com/en) Of course there are and other tools for web developement such as [adobe dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/).

Comment: Thanks, though I think I need a little more understanding of why I am exactly trying to do here. Maybe I am going to post as a different question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most Java IDEs are capable of developing every kind of web products:

- relatively static content - HTML, CSS, JS
- Virtualizable languages with some intermediate platform (.NET or Java)
- scripting languages - PHP, Python, Ruby

I'm talking about Eclipse and NetBeans in particular. They both present most phases required for a comfortable development, web server integration, debuggin services, including XML support, connectivity with FTP/SVN, ant/maven, autocomplete, inner search into file structure and frameworks and so on.

Btw Aptana is Eclipse based, but I prefer Eclipse PDT or Eclipse Web tools platform.

Answer (score 0):

netbeans is pretty kool i have been using it for two years, and if your using php, it has a great php plugin!! http://netbeans.org/features/php/    hope that helps.

solomon saleh

Comment: you could also try using php eclipse!!

Comment: Not using php... Mostly JS with maybe a little bit of webGL though to be honest till I was given my assignment I had not even heard of it... :P

Comment: netbeans deos still come all the html,javascript,jquery and ajax built into it automatically!! so it could be used for that aswell!!